# While installing php7.3 it shows "Unable to locate package php7.3-fpm"

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

While installing php-fpm it shows an error:

> E: Unable to locate package php7.3
>
> E: Unable to locate package php7.3-fpm

Please tell me, how to solve this issue.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server.

Comment: How did you try to install it?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.3 may not be available in Ubuntu 16.04 default repo, you need to add third party repo. I have used ondrej repo quiet often and it works great.

Run the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.3
```

You will need sudo permission to run the above commands.

Comment: Still the problem is persist
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3'

Comment: try 'sudo apt-get install php7.3' do not try php-fpm yet. have you already run 'sudo apt-get update'  and 'sudo apt-get upgrade' ?